# Problem in executing objExcel.Application.Run with Path having special characters

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code which I have to run the macro `MyMacro` in another workbook named `Test File Sep20.xlsm`. This code works without any error.

```
Sub Run_Macro()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Path = "F:\RO\Data Management_Mar20"
    
        If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MsgBox "File does not exist !!!"
            End
        Else
            objExcel.Application.Run _
            "'F:\RO\Data Management_Mar20\Test File Sep20.xlsm'!Module1.MyMacro"
        End If
        
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.Application.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

However if I add single quote i.e. `'` & or `.` in the Workbook Name & Path and change the code appropriately (please see code below with remarks), it gives out Run-time error '1004' saying Macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled

```
Sub Run_Macro()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Path = "F:\RO\Data Management_Mar'20"      'Added single quote in month
    
        If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MsgBox "File does not exist !!!"
            End
        Else
            'Run-time error '1004' at below line
            objExcel.Application.Run _
            "'F:\RO\Data Management_Mar'20\ _
               1.0 Test File Sep'20.xlsm'!Module1.MyMacro"     'Added . & ' in path
        End If
        
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.Application.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried various ways such as writing `Chr(39)` instead of `'` or wrapping up contents after `objExcel.Application.Run` in `"" ""` but to no avail.

Seeking support here to handle the menace of `'` & `.`, after I am exhausted trying.

Comment: Remove the line wrap and then try it.  Also - is your macro file already open?

Comment: See also here for how to deal with `'` - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Comment: Tried without wrap & file is not open too... Doesn't work. Will check out the contents of article.

Comment: You can't use `Application.Run` on a closed file

Comment: @TimWilliams First code very much works without any fuss.

Comment: @TimWilliams The Note given in the link you provided has helped. I am mentioning the same in answer below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mentioned note available in [this link](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm) provided by Tim Williams in comment section above did the wonders.

Note: If your workbook name contains apostrophe (') characters, such as in "Joe's Workbook.xls", then you need to double-up the apostrophes like Application.Run "'Joe''s Workbook'!MyMacroName"

The corrected code is :

```
Sub Run_Macro()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Path = "F:\RO\Data Management_Mar'20"
    
        If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MsgBox "File does not exist !!!"
            End
        Else
            'Resolutuion : Apostrophe (') characters doubled-up
            objExcel.Application.Run _
            "'F:\RO\Data Management_Mar''20\1.0 Test File Sep''20.xlsm'!Module1.MyMacro"  
        End If
        
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.Application.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```